# htaccess subdomain script redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having problems understanding how htaccess redirects work:

Can I do a background redirect, so that the user sees `[subdomain].mydomain.com/?p1=v1...`, but the server delivers `mydomain.com/?sid=[subdomain]&p1=v1...` without actual redirection, only server side.

This is what I have so far, it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.localhost\.com/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) localhost.com/index.php?supplier=$1&$2 [L]
```

I doesn't change anything.

**Edit**

I got this halfway working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.localhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /(.+)$ http://localhost\.com/eshop/?supplier=%1 [QSA,P]
```

Now I get a nice forbidden warning, if I remove the P flag it'll redirect, so the URL shows `http://localhost.com/eshop/?supplier=[subdomain]&p1=v1...` like it should, but the user must still see `http://[subdomain].localhost.com/eshop/?p1=v1...`, now how the remove that forbidden part...

(Notice my website is actually in a folder under *www*, but the *eshop* part will go away).

**EDIT 2**

IT WORKS, so as *clmarquart* said I needed mod_proxy. On WAMP you have to enable it by clicking on the tray icon->Apache->Apache modules and I enabled proxy_module and proxy_http_module, whatever they are.

Comment: In order to use the `[P]` flag, you need to have `mod_proxy` enabled. Otherwise, what you have should work.

Comment: What's that? How do I check on WAMP?

Comment: Modules are enabled in the `conf/httpd.conf` file.  You will want to make sure that your hosting provider has it enabled as well.  Enabled apache modules should show up on a phpinfo page as well `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "P" flag to force use of the internal proxy. The RewriteURL target must be a full URL when using the proxy module. Use "%1" to "%9" as the captured data from the RewriteCond expression, and "$1" to "$9" for the captured data from the RewriteRule expression.

The following should work better (not tested though)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.localhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://localhost.com/index.php?supplier=%1&$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: I'd like to get the [subdomain] part with a $_GET, is that possible somehow? Since it redirects internally I'd think yes... What you gave me doesn't work unfortunately, I'm still smashing my keyboard to see if by miracle I get it to work. Currently I get a broken link error. Also what's inside this (.+) of the RewriteRule?

Comment: %1 will give you the subdomain. $1 will give you the (.+) capture of the RewriteRule